# currentTime update via scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a video.  As the user scrolls down I'd like the video to progress ahead and vise versa.  I have the video working along with the scroll but the wall I keep hitting is the equation to go along with it.

As the bottom of the video comes into view, I'd like to progress and have it finish mid browser height. The only problem is, sometimes these videos are at the bottom of the page.

How would I go about writing an evaluation that will calculate the currentTime of the video correctly? Below is one version of an attempt.

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

videos[i].currentTime = ((videos[i].duration/($(window).height()+$(videos[i]).height()))*scrollTop);
```

Comment: "As the bottom of the video comes into view the video should begin progressing and should finish mid vertical browsers."
This sentence makes no sense... could you elaborate?

Comment: yeah basically what I mean is that once the video is scroll into view the currentTime should start being updated based on the scrolling.  Say the video is 10 seconds long, as it comes into view the current time will be 0 and as the user scrolls up the currentTime progresses to 10 once the video is mid browser height.

Comment: So you want to use the vertical scroll bar as a seek bar, and only when you can actually see the top half of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. An example page would be great but, here is a little portion of untested code that, if you're doing what I think you're doing, should work.

```
videos[i].currentTime = (window.scrollTop-findPos(videos[i])[1])/(videos[i].duration/2);
```

Where findPos is a function such as this one from QuirksMode which finds the position of the video on the page.

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
}
```